# echo() in PHP 5.3.17 producing odd results

Tags: php, linux

I updated PHP on my server to 5.3.17, which is the newest stable version.

For some reason, this echo statement is producing unexpected results:

```
<?  
echo ('<p style="color:#808080;">Hello, <em>'.$_SESSION["user"].'</em>');
?>
```

Result:

```
Hello, '.$_SESSION["user"].';
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: what happens if you put `<?php` instead of short tags (`<?`)?

Comment: Try removing ( ), echo is a construct, not a function.

Comment: Also, you didn't close `<p>` tag.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: The closing `</p>` is optional in HTML.

Comment: Any sources for that statement? I know that browsers will handle that, but is that an argument to not close them?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html. No, it's not an argument not to close them, but it's also not a problem :)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk If you're interested, the same rules also apply to table rows/cells. :)

Comment: I always close tags in my HTML code (and if you don't, I will find you and make you write closed `</p>` tag 100 times on the chalk board :)), but still - good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You probably don't have `short_open_tags` enabled.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) Use the full open tag (`<?php`) instead, or turn it on in `php.ini`.